# Refresh JWT token from AWS Cognito in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito

I am creating users in amazon cognito via the aws sdk cognito .net sdk.  When a user logs in, they get back 3 tokens (IdToken, AccessToken, and RefreshToken).  The IdToken is valid for 1 hour.  Currently when the token expires, the user is redirected to the login page.  What I would like to do is send the RefreshToken when I receive a 403 back, but I am not sure how to do this in the angular app?

I am also assuming this is something I would handle on the client side and not on the server side (.net web api)?

I currently have guards on my routes that call the following function from my service:

```
 loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired('token');
  }
```

The following works, but the problem is I have to use my `AccessKey` and `SecretKey`:

```
refreshToken(){

    AWS.config.update({credentials:{accessKeyId:'access_id',secretAccessKey:'secret'}, region:'us-east-2'});

    const myCreds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId:'us-east-2:identity_pool_id},{region:'us-east-2'});

   const myConfig = new AWS.Config({credentials: myCreds, region: 'us-east-2'});



   const refreshToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rToken'));
    const cognitoisp = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    const params = {
      AuthFlow: 'REFRESH_TOKEN',
      ClientId: 'client_id',
      UserPoolId: 'user_pool_id',
      AuthParameters: {
        'REFRESH_TOKEN': refreshToken
      }
    }

    cognitoisp.adminInitiateAuth(params,(err,data)=>{
      if(err) console.log(err,err.stack);

      else

      {
        this.token = data.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
        localStorage.setItem('lcToken',JSON.stringify(this.token));
      }

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right idea there, once you get 4xx status you can use the refresh token to get a fresh set of tokens. The code in JavaScript goes like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const cognitoisp = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

var params = {
  AuthFlow: 'REFRESH_TOKEN',
  ClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  UserPoolId: 'region_xxxxxxxx',
  AuthParameters: {
    'REFRESH_TOKEN': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
}

cognitoisp.adminInitiateAuth(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

DOCS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminInitiateAuth-property

Comment: So I can basically do the same functionality with .NET right.  If I get a 401, I can call the AdminInititateAuth on the server side sending in the proper header?  or is it better to to this javascript side as you did?  Are clientId and UserPoolId things that should be private (can i store them in js)?  Is it best to do this send a refresh token in my guard code?

Comment: its better to handle this on the client's side but it can also be done on the server side, both ways work.
One thing to note is that the refresh token has to be expired for the call to return successfully, if your token hasn't expired it will return an exception.

Comment: `the refresh token has to be expired` - Did you mean the `IdToken`?

Comment: yeah i meant idToken, but looks like that's not a limitation, you can refresh anytime

Comment: Ok thanks, I am putting some code together and will update my post soon

Comment: Getting this error - ConfigError: Missing region in config

Comment: @MDM For the javascript sdk just add this `AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});`

Comment: CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config